# Getting error ParametricNDSolve::ndnum: from ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

```
arec = 1/1100;
aeq = 1/(2.4*10^4*0.13);
alpha = (arec/aeq)^1/2;
y = (alpha*x)^2 + 2*alpha*x;
yb = y*(0.02/0.13);
yc = y*(0.11/0.13);
xi = 10^-3;
xrec = (((alpha^2 + 1)^1/2) - 1)/alpha;
n = 2*alpha*(alpha*x + 1)/((alpha*x)^2 + 2*alpha*x);
n0 = 2*alpha*(alpha*xi + 1)/((alpha*xi)^2 + 2*alpha*xi);

c = 
  ParametricNDSolve[
    {phi'[x] == -n*phi[x] + ((3*n^2/2*k)*(vg[x] (4/3 + y + yc) + vc[x]*yc[x])/(1 + y)), 
     dc'[x] == -k*vc[x] + 3*phi'[x], vc'[x] == -n*vc[x] + k*phi[x], 
     dg'[x] == -(3/4)*k*vg[x] + 4*phi'[x], 
     vg'[x] == ((1 + (3/4)*yb)^-1)*(-(3/4)*yb*n*vg[x] + (1/4)*k*dg[x]) +k*phi[x], 
     phi[xi] == 1, 
     dc[xi] == (3/4)*dg[xi], 
     vc[xi] == vg[xi], 
     dg[xi] == -2*phi[xi], 
     vg[xi] == -(1/4)*(k/n0)*dg[xi]}, 
    {phi, dc, vc, dg, vg}, {x, xi, xrec}, {k}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[phi[k][x] /. c, {k, 0.01, 1}]], {x, xi, xrec}]
```

When I run this code, the `NDSolve part` gives a parametric function, and it 
seems OK, but when I plot, I get the following error:

> ParametricNDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.001`.

What is the problem with my code? Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: I think your initial condition are bad. The reason the problem doesn't show up until you try to plot is because `ParametricNDSolveValue` doesn't do any solving, it just set things up for `NDSolve` to solve when a numerical value for the parameter has been given.

Answer (score 3):

After correcting a couple of typos, the code works.

```
arec = 1/1100;
aeq = 1/(2.4*10^4*0.13);
alpha = (arec/aeq)^1/2;
y = (alpha*x)^2 + 2*alpha*x;
yb = y*(0.02/0.13);
yc = y*(0.11/0.13);
xi = 10^-3;
xrec = (((alpha^2 + 1)^1/2) - 1)/alpha;
n = 2*alpha*(alpha*x + 1)/((alpha*x)^2 + 2*alpha*x);
n0 = 2*alpha*(alpha*xi + 1)/((alpha*xi)^2 + 2*alpha*xi);

c = ParametricNDSolve[{phi'[
     x] == -n*
      phi[x] + ((3*n^2/2*
         k)*(vg[x] (4/3 + y + yc) + vc[x]*yc)/(1 + y)), 
   dc'[x] == -k*vc[x] + 3*phi'[x], vc'[x] == -n*vc[x] + k*phi[x], 
   dg'[x] == -(3/4)*k*vg[x] + 4*phi'[x], 
   vg'[x] == ((1 + (3/4)*yb)^-1)*(-(3/4)*yb*n*vg[x] + (1/4)*k*dg[x]) +
      k*phi[x], phi[xi] == 1, dc[xi] == (3/4)*dg[xi], 
   vc[xi] == vg[xi], dg[xi] == -2*phi[xi], 
   vg[xi] == -(1/4)*(k/n0)*dg[xi]}, {phi, dc, vc, dg, vg}, {x, xi, 
   xrec}, {k}];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[phi[k][x] /. c, {k, 0.01, 1, .3}]], {x, xi, xrec},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "phi"}]
```

[image: fig1]